# Make file read/write for all users during installation

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2011

I need to make a file read/write for all users during install. Right now, the file is only read/write for admins and only read for non admins.

I am using InstallShield Premier 2010. The problem is I am very new to this product and not quite sure how to achieve this. The help files were little to no help. Any ideas on how to achieve this using InstallShield.

I would also be open to a non InstallShield way of doing things if it exists.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click a file or a folder, select Properties and then click "Permissions" button. Another solution is to use [XCACLS.EXE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318754) as a custom action.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however right clicking the files wont be possible because it has to run during the installation process. Also, it seems as if XCACLS.exe pertains to Windows 2000. If it is still valid for XP or later, adding it as a custom action would def be a option. Have you used it with XP or later or in a situation similar to mine?

Comment: For right-click I was referring to the InstallShield application. Select the files and folders page in your project so you can configure the files and folders. Also XCACLS works on newer Windows versions, including Vista and Windows 7. You need to run it as deferred with no impersonation.

Comment: Awesome, I was actually able to get it to work with a combination of setting Install Shield permissions and using XCACLS. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better question would be, should you do this?

[You Can’t Fake It ‘Til You Make It with Standard Users](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2011/04/23/you-can-t-fake-it-til-you-make-it-with-standard-users.aspx)